# page.setRequestInterceptionEnabled(true) prevents page from fully loading all components in puppeteer

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

## Steps to reproduce

- Create a page
- Set request interception to true
- Goto https://google.com/maps/search/google with waitUntil: 'networkidle0'
- Place listings on the left hand side is not visible (on desktop).

## My Environment:

Puppeteer version: 2.1.1
Platform / OS version: MacOS Catalina (10.15.3)
URLs (if applicable): https://google.com/maps/search/google
Node.js version: v12.9.0

## What steps will reproduce the problem?

```
const page = await this.browser.newPage();

await page.setRequestInterception(true);

page.on('request', (req) => { req.continue(); });

page.goto('https://google.com/maps/search/google');
```

What is the expected result?
To see the found listings/places on the left sidebar (open link in your own browser if you want to see what I mean).

What happens instead?
Left sidebar with listings does not load when I use page.setRequestInterception(true);

Am I missing something here?
I've tried hundreds of things to make it work, but didn't find a solution.

What would be an alternative option to intercept and block specific requests in puppeteer?
Create my own proxy, etc.?

Comment: found a lot similar issue on official repo, i suggest avoid `setRequestInterception`, what's your goal here?, is there any other ways to achieve it?

Comment: I'm trying to block some user preference & tracking related requests. The only other solution I could come up, without using `setRequestInterception`. Is that I create my own proxy service that block's those requests.

Comment: hey i wrote simple script same as yours, Left sidebar with listings loaded, my puppeteer version is 1.18.1

Answer (score 0):

async def go_to_fmoviez(url, MAX_CONCURRENT_DOWNLOADS = 1):
browser = await pyppeteer.launch({"executablePath": "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe", "headless": True})
page = await browser.newPage()
await stealth(page)

```
try:
    playlist = await get_iframe_url(page, url)   
    print("closing the browser")
    await browser.close()
    print(playlist)
    return playlist

except Exception as e:
    print("closing the browser")
    await browser.close()
    raise e
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).